# Binding backward-kill-word to Ctrl+w

Tags: bash, readline

I'm trying to switch from prolonged use of Tcsh to recent exploration of Bash.

I've managed to port over all my favorite features, except for Ctrl+w which treats spaces and slashes as word boundaries, most likely backward-kill-word. In Bash however readline deletes all the way to the first space, deleting all slashes between.

I've tried many various combinations of \C-w: backward-kill-word in both .inputrc and .bashrc using bind but I can't get it to work the way I want.

Funny enough, through Putty from Windows at work I can use Alt+Backspace, which also the manual says is the default binding, to produce the exact behavior I want. But in Terminal.app on my Macs at home this does not work. Same goes for any FreeBSD or Linux server I happen to be logged into from Terminal.app.

So I turn to superuser for help.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

`readline` does not bind over <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>W</kbd> since it is handled by the terminal driver by default:

```
$ stty -a
(...) werase = ^W; (...)
```

To disable this, you have to run (in `~/.bashrc`):

```
stty werase undef
bind '"\C-w": backward-kill-word'
```

`.inputrc` will not help here since it is read when <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>W</kbd> is still assigned to `werase`.

Also note that `\C-w` format keyseqs must be enclosed in double-quotes, as above.

---

Different terminals may handle <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Backspace</kbd> differently.

- PuTTY and GNOME Terminal (with default settings) send `1b 7f` (`ESC DEL`)
- Xterm with `metaSendsEscape: true` sends `1b 08` (`ESC BS`).
- Xterm *without* `metaSendsEscape` sends `88` ([`HTS`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C0_and_C1_control_codes#C1_.28ISO_8859_and_Unicode.29), or `BS` with highest bit set).

Xterm has a few settings to control the behavior of <kbd>Alt</kbd> key (called <kbd>Meta</kbd> in Xterm and X11 in general). With `metaSendsEscape`, holding <kbd>Alt</kbd> will prefix the keypress with an `ESC` (hex `1b`). Without the setting (default mode), <kbd>Alt</kbd> will set the highest bit of the input character, resulting in special characters. (For example, <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>N</kbd> results in `ESC n` and `î` respectively.)

As far as I can remember, Terminal.app also has a similar setting to control the behavior of Meta/Alt/whatever-Macs-use.

Comment: This is not only the best answer but extremely informative, thank you!

Comment: This is fantastic! Is there a reason that some keys are bound in stty and others in readline, though?

Comment: @shurane: The *werase* "word erase" action, like normal erase (Backspace), is implemented by the OS itself, in the "tty device" driver -- notice that they are available even in programs that just blindly read from stdin, e.g. `cat`. On all Unixes, `stty` is used to control various tty parameters including these special keys. (Here's how [UNIX 7th Edition `stty`](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=stty&manpath=Unix+Seventh+Edition) looked like.)

Comment: @shurane: Meanwhile, *readline* is a userspace library originally written for the *bash* shell (although now used by many programs). It's possible that the other actions were implemented in *readline* to avoid bloating the tty driver (which already had a considerable amount of flags and toggles, as seen in `stty`'s manual). Also, *bash* was originally intended for the [GNU OS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_operating_system) and only later ported to other Unixes; it is much easier to maintain the editing features in a single library than in several very different kernels.

Comment: @shurane: Technically, however, **all** these actions, including word erase, are implemented by *readline* -- when active, it completely disables Backspace and Ctrl+W handling by the terminal driver. *readline* just respects the `stty` configuration for simplicity, but it can be overriden by *readline*'s own settings (as described in Matt Day's answer).

Comment: This is a great answer for information, upvote. However, it should be noted that this disables Ctrl-w for all programs unless they use readline, which is probably not what anyone wants..., so try @fjarlq 's answer.

Answer (score 21):

If you `set bind-tty-special-chars off` in your `.inputrc`, you can then customize the behavior of the special terminal chars.

For example:

```
set bind-tty-special-chars off
Control-u: kill-whole-line
Control-w: backward-kill-word
```

Comment: And this has the benefit of working for all programs that use readline—e.g., `python`.

Answer (score 4):

For the record, the answer as it applies to iTerm2 is to set <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Backspace</kbd> (or <kbd>Opt ⌥</kbd>-<kbd>⌫</kbd> on Mac) to send Hex Codes `0xb1` and `0x7f` in order to perform the `backward-kill-word` action which *treats non-alphanumeric characters as delimiters.*

For distinction, here's the behavior I'm describing, in which pressing <kbd>Opt ⌥</kbd>-<kbd>⌫</kbd> one time changes this:

`echo "/example/filepath/with_non-alpha.characters@blah:meh`

to this:

`echo "/example/filepath/with_non-alpha.characters@blah:`

And subsequent presses of <kbd>Opt ⌥</kbd>-<kbd>⌫</kbd>:

`echo "/example/filepath/with_non-alpha.characters@`

`echo "/example/filepath/with_non-alpha.`

`echo "/example/filepath/with_non-`

`echo "/example/filepath/with_`

`echo "/example/filepath/`

Here's what the setting looks like in iTerm2:
[image]

So, specific to Putty and Terminal, [grawity's answer](https://superuser.com/a/212455/233732) is great. But having spent an embarrassing amount of time looking for how to apply the setting in iTerm2, this superuser post seems to come up most frequently, so it seemed responsible to provide the relevant info as it applies to iTerm2 as an Answer attached to this Question.

Comment: It took me a long time indeed to figure this out, and this solution works indeed on OS X (with iTerm2) when logging in on a remote bash shell. Thanks!