# Bind CTRL+W to werase (default bash behaviour in Linux/PuTTY) in iTerm2

Tags: macos, bash, keyboard-shortcuts, readline, iterm2

I use a Mac at home and have changed my modifier keys swapping Command and <kbd>CTRL</kbd>, so <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> spawns a new tab in chrome, <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> is copy and so forth. I use Windows/Linux at work and I want a consistent layout between these OSes (not having to consciously switch to Command on OSX and back to <kbd>CTRL</kbd> when at work).

I've installed iTerm2 to replace OSX Terminal, this allows me to capture <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> without having it kill the window. I don't know what to bind this shortcut to in order to emulate the default behaviour in bash/puTTY ([werase](https://superuser.com/questions/212446/binding-backward-kill-word-to-ctrlw)?) where it deletes text before the cursor up to the first space.

```
find . -name "my.file" -type
```

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> would delete '-type' from the above command leaving:

```
find . -name "my.file"
```

Comment: How about all the other commands? Most of ⌃A-Z and ⌘A-Z are already bound to some action at least in iTerm and Terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Put this line, quotes and all, in your `~/.inputrc` file (you may have to restart Bash after you edit that file):

```
"\C-w": backward-kill-word
```

Comment: Doesn't answer the question, as the user swapped control and command, meaning he actually wants to handle command-w.

Comment: @GregK If your CTRL key can do other things you expect to work in Bash (e.g., CTRL-B moves the cursor back one character) then I believe my answer above will work for you.  If not, then Daniel is right.