# Bash readline deleting till the previous slash

Tags: linux, bash, readline

In Bash Emacs mode, is there any way to delete till the previous slash character?

For example, if I entered the command `cp /usr/local/bin/reallylongincorrectfolder /home/myname/reallylong_and_correct_path` and want to just delete the `reallylongincorrectfolder`, is there any shortcut?

This is a very common scenario for me in Bash.

Something like `dF<char>` in vi?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
bind -P |grep unix-filename-rubout
```

To test out the keybinding with eg. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>b</kbd>:

```
bind \\C-b:unix-filename-rubout
```

For permanent usage, add it to `~/.inputrc`

Comment: To add it to `~/.inputrc`, add a line like this to that file: `"\C-b": unix-filename-rubout`.  To see the effect, you'll have to start a new bash shell (or run some other program that uses the GNU readline library).

Answer (score 19):

<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Backspace</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>w</kbd> are commonly mapped to `backward-kill-word`, which does that. If you want to find out what it's mapped to on your system (if anything), run `bind -P | grep '^backward-kill-word'`.

As explained by [@Barmar](https://superuser.com/questions/606212/bash-readline-deleting-till-the-previous-slash/606217#comment748999_606217), this is different from `unix-word-rubout`, which removes to the previous space boundary.

Comment: But that will kill the entire word.. I want to kill only till the last slash

Comment: It does remove only to the last slash here. Slash is one of the default word separators. [Are you sure you're using Bash?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/444951/zsh-stop-backward-kill-word-on-directory-delimiter)

Comment: My bad.. Alt-Backspace does remove it till the last slash.What is the difference between ALt-BackSpace and Ctrl-W ?

Comment: Ctl-w is normally bound to `unix-word-rubout`: _Kill the word behind point, using white space as a word boundary._

Comment: This doesn't exactly work. "Words are composed of alphanumeric characters (letters and digits)". Hence it'll stop at much more than just slashes. The default-unbound `unix-filename-rubout` is slightly better, since it'll stop at white space and slash.

Comment: `alt` + `backspace` deletes until `/`, thus answering the question. `ctrl` + `w` on the other hand deletes until the previous space.

Comment: I couldn't set `backward-kill-word` to `ctrl` + `w` using `bind` or `~/.inputrc` - but this answer did the trick: https://superuser.com/questions/212446/binding-backward-kill-word-to-ctrlw you first need to `stty werase undef`

Answer (score 12):

Put this in your `.inputrc` and start a new shell:

`C-b:unix-filename-rubout`

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>b</kbd> now erases backwards to the next slash.

Nirvana!

Don't forget <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>X</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>E</kbd> will launch your editor so you can edit a complicated command line comfortably.